# Jquery mobile navbar font weight

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi, I am using this custom css code for my nav bar active tab.

```
.ui-btn-active
{
  border: 0px;
  background: red !important;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red ,#111)!important;       
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Look at home it's pretty slim as compared to other navigation links second home bar height is more than others.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the other links have a border assigned.  By removing the border for the active tab (`border:0px;`), you shift shift the link up.